# Filter on different graph edge types using ArangoDb AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

Assuming I have the following document collections:

- Students with names and student Id
- Classes with name and class Id
- Locations with name and location Id

and the following edge collections specifying the relationships:

- StudentClass with _from and _to references as well as starting and end dates
- ClassLocations with just  _from and _to references

What is the best way to return a graph for a student for a given date showing the classes and locations? I have been using something like the following, but it's returning StudentClass edges that do not fall within the date range.  Also, since the filter is not on the path I believe that all edges will be traversed meaning that this may not scale well.

```
FOR v, e, p
IN 1..10 OUTBOUND "Students/1234"
StudentClass, ClassLocations 
FILTER ((e.endDate > "2017-10-01") AND (e.startDate < "2017-10-01"))
 OR (e.endDate == null)
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mark.arangodb I've been able to create a working solution:

```
FOR v, e, p
IN 1..10 OUTBOUND "Students/1234"
StudentClass, ClassLocations 
FILTER p.edges[*].startDate ALL <= @date
LET counter = (FOR e2 IN p.edges 
               FILTER NOT_NULL(e2.endDate, @date) >= @date 
               RETURN e2)
FILTER COUNT(counter) == COUNT(p.edges) 
RETURN p
```

The first filter ensures that all edges must have a startDate prior to the date given (as a string) in the @date bind parameter.  An edge without the startDate property passes this filter.  (ArangoDb must treat null as a value less than anything.)

The LET statement creates a variable called "counter" and assigns it to an array of edges that either have an endDate greater than the given date or that don't have an endDate.  The final filter only allows paths which have the same number of edges as those in the "counter" variable.